# Not getting response from GSM Modem using AT command

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, serial-port, gsm, at-command

I am learning AT Command in c#.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        String command = "AT";
        SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort
                                    {
                                        PortName = "COM4",
                                        BaudRate = 9600,
                                        DataBits = 8,
                                        Parity = Parity.None,
                                        ReadTimeout = 300,
                                        WriteTimeout = 300,
                                        StopBits = StopBits.One,
                                        Handshake = Handshake.None
                                    };
        serialPort.Open();
        serialPort.WriteLine(command + "\r");
        String outPut = serialPort.ReadExisting();

        Console.WriteLine(outPut);


    }
```

I am sure about the **PortName**. What I am doing wrong in the program??

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/636758/serial-port-readline-vs-readexisting-or-how-to-read-the-data-from-serial-port-pr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to tell if it's your only problem but [`SerialPort.ReadExisting()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.readexisting.aspx) only reads the data that is *immediately* available (ie in the stream and buffer).

Your program writes data to the modem, and calls `ReadExisting()` right away. `ReadExisting` will return immediately with no data available, since the modem has had no time to respond.

Comment: I have modified my code like below.
`SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort
                                        {//previus properties
                                            RtsEnable = true,
                                            DtrEnable = true
                                        };


            serialPort.Open();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            serialPort.WriteLine("AT" + "\r");
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            String outPut = serialPort.ReadLine();
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Console.WriteLine(outPut);
            serialPort.Close();`

Comment: First time the programs output is ok when I plugin the modem in the PC but after that it shows **The operation has timed out** Any idea??
What I am doing wrong +Joachim Isaksson